# Python Xampp Error: End of script output before headers

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, apache, xampp

I am using a mac computer and trying to run python in Xampp. When I run php it works fine. But when running python I get this error:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: file_name.py
```

I followed what other people have said with editing the httpd.conf file in etc with `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py`
but it still doesn't work. I have tried making the python file executable with `chmod +x file_name` but that isn't working either. It could be my shebang line, or maybe there is some other step I have to do.

My python script is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("<html><head></head>")
print("<body><h1>Hello World</h1></body>")
print("</html>")
```

I also tried using the shebang line:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

which is what I get from `which python3` but also is not working.

Anyone have any advice?